# Problem when sending dictionary with ajax ( POST ) to python ( django views ) -> always empty

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

So i call this in the head of the html :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then with a button i call a function :

```html
        <div>
            <button class= "button" type="ajax-call" onclick="getValue();">Envoyer</button>
        </div>
```

And the function is :

```js
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function getValue(){

                ....


                $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'sondage' %}",
                type : 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {heure_reponse: heure, jour_reponse: jour,habitude_reponse: habit, faim_reponse : faim, soif_reponse: soif, estomac_reponse:estomac, miam_reponse: miam, quantite_reponse: quantite, but_reponse: but, adresse_reponse: adresse, identifiant_reponse:identifiant
                }
                })

            }

        </script>
```

The problem is : When i write in the views.py of my django site ( python ) with

```js
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.shortcuts import render

from csv import writer
from csv import QUOTE_MINIMAL

@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def sondage(request):
    #Récupération des données par ajax
    reponses = request.POST.items()
    reponses = list(reponses)
    if len(reponses) == 0:
      print(" AJAX PROBLEME ")
    reponses.append(request.user.get_filename().split('/')[1].split('.')[0])
    name = request.user.get_filename().split('/')[1].split('.')[0]
    #Ecriture dans le csv
    write_csv(reponses,name)
    #Appel de la page que l'on est en train de traiter
    return render(request, 'sondage.html',{'data':reponses})


def write_csv(data,name):
    #Ouverture en mode APPEND
    with open('uploads/questionnaire/sondage.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
      csv_writer =  writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
      csv_writer.writerow(data)
    csvfile.close()
```

I always have "AJAX PROBLEME" ! Why ? And how do we fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

you should convert you data dict like this

```
var dict_data = {heure_reponse: heure, jour_reponse: jour,habitude_reponse: habit, faim_reponse : faim, soif_reponse: soif, estomac_reponse:estomac, miam_reponse: miam, quantite_reponse: quantite, but_reponse: but, adresse_reponse: adresse, identifiant_reponse:identifiant}
```

`const data= JSON.stringify(dict_data)`

```
$.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'sondage' %}",
                type : 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                data: data})
```

then send it
and in  Django view fetch like this

```
data = json.loads(request.POST['data'])
```

Comment: When i do this, i have a MultiValueDictKeyError with 'data'.

Comment: Do you know how to resolve this ?

Comment: @Alexandre RODRIGUEZ updated ans please go through one more time